# Should I noindex blocks used for parts of the template created as posts in Yoast?

Tags: seo, noindex, yoast

I am setting up Yoast SEO plugin.

I am using a theme that creates HTML blocks. For example the footer is a block, which means that as a block, it's a custom post type, and applies for Yoast SEO set up.

Should I `noindex` these posts to make Googlebot ignore the footer post and other blocks? Or will I, by disabling indexing in this custom posts, make the whole pages go ambiguous?

Comment: I guess that what your worried about is that creating these as a "post" creates a page for it with its own URL.  Is Googlebot even going to find the URL that contains only your footer?  Is it linked from anywhere else on your site?

Comment: Hello Stephen, it is not linked anywhere. Howevere you're right that wordpress creates a url for this "block", and I don't know how googles indexes this... I have "no index" these blocks in yoast,and I don't see the no index tag in the page, which I suppose means that the pages / site is still being properly indexed...

Answer (score 2):

> Please be mindful with noindex directives: most search engines will
>   honour it, even if it's in the BODY element.

-Gary Illyes of Google
https://twitter.com/methode/status/611299524682891264

In order words, if there are NOINDEX NOFOLLOW tags anywhere on your page, this could cause Google to completely deindex the entire page, or your entire site if it's on all of your pages in your footer.

It is fine to add NOINDEX NOFOLLOW to header/footer elements so that Google isn't indexing your header.php and footer.php files. But if the NOINDEX/NOFOLLOW tags are thus added to other pages on your site, anywhere in your HTML code because of your inclusion of your header/footer files, then this could cause massive derankings.